# Is the subset of a relatively compact set relatively compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, compact-operators

I am trying to read a paper and there is something I do not understand.

Given a compact set $K \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and a set $A \subset K $ and a compact operator $T:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m $, I am trying to determine if $A-T(K) $ which I **think** is defined as 
$$A-T(k)= \bigcup_{x \in K} A-T(x) $$ where $A-T(x)$ is translating all point in $A$ by $T(x)$. This is not explicitly mentioned in the paper so its what I assume.

Now clearly $A$ being a subset of a compact set , its relatively compact and since $T$ is a compact operator , $T(K)$ is relatively compact .

Can I also say that $A-T(K)$ defined above is relatively compact?

I tried to argue using the sequential  compactness definition but couldn't prove it .

If the above is true can I conclude as in the compact case that its subset is relatively compact? Why?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you asking if the set $A - T(x)$ is relatively compact in $K$? Or in some range-set?

Comment: @Jason I am asking several things at the same time. First : Is A-T(K) relatively compact  set in $\mathbb{R}^m$? If yes then Second: Can I conclude that its subset $A-T(x)$ is relatively compact too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A-T(K)$ is relatively compact in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. $T$ is a bounded operator, so the image of any bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ under $T$ will be relatively compact. Therefore, it follows from $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ being compact that $T(K)$ is relatively compact. Any subset of a compact set is at least relatively compact, which means that $A\subset K$ is guaranteed to be relatively compact. All you need to show $A-T(K)$'s relative compactness is that cl$(A-T(K))$ is bounded, which clearly follows from the fact that both $A$ and $T(K)$ are both relatively compact.

Regarding $A-T(x)$ for a particular $x \in K$, consider what it would mean if $A-T(x)$ was not relatively compact. It would imply that $T(x)$ was unbounded for some $x \in K$--a compact space. This directly contradicts the fact that $T$ is a bounded operator, so it can't be the case. We now have that for all $x \in K, \ T(x)$ is bounded. Combine this with the fact that $A$ is bounded, and it follows that for all $x \in K$, cl$(A - T(x))$ is bounded, so $A-T(x)$ is relatively compact.

Comment: we can only say for sure that $T(K)$ is relatively compact if K is compact. Image of bounded subset needn't necessarily be compact, it just  needs to be bounded if T is bounded

Comment: Ahhh, right you are. My mistake; I'll change that.

Comment: @Cavin Do you know if a continuous function has an infimum on a relatively compact set?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily does. Take an open interval for example, say $(0,1)$. This interval is bounded, so it's relatively compact. But if you consider the infimum of $f(x) = x$ on $(0,1)$, you get arg $\inf_{x \in (0,1)}f(x)=0$, and $0 \notin (0,1)$.